# If the union of two sets is contained in the intersection, then one is contained in the other ($[A\cup B\subseteq A\cap B]\implies A \subseteq B$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Let $A\cup B\subseteq A\cap B.$ Prove that $A\subseteq  B.$

My understanding of this question is that all the elements of set $A$ that intersects with set $B$ exists in the union of sets $A$ and $B$ and because in order for the elements to intersect, the elements must exist in both sets $A$ and $B$. Therefore set $A$ is a subset of $B$.

My question is how do I write the proof down so that it is an acceptable answer? Also does this mean set $B$ is a subset of $A$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$A\subseteq A\cup B\subseteq A\cap B \subseteq B.$$
Similarly $B\subseteq A.$ Hence $A=B$

Comment: Where does that $=$ come from in the first line?  Don't you mean $A\subseteq A\cup B \subseteq A\cap B \subseteq B$ ?

Comment: @EwanMellor Your version would slightly more clearly be using the given assumption, but since $A\cap B \subseteq A \cup B$ is straightforward, using the equals sign is fine too.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose, we have an element $x$ with $x\in B$, but $x$ is not element of $A$

Then, $x$ is in the union of $A$ and $B$, but not in the intersection.
This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

How do u proceed when you need to show one set is contained in another?
Take an element in first one and somehow try to show it in second one.
Here let x belongs to A, then x belongs to A union B, now using given condition we will get x belongs to A intersection B, thus x belongs to B, which is precisely you need to show.

Comment: Similarly you can show B is a subset of A.

Answer (score 2):

$$A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B $$ 
$$A \cap B \subseteq B\subseteq A \cup B$$

If $A \cup B\subseteq A \cap B $, then the ends are squeezed and $A = B$.